# remove event listener with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I am trying to remove some listeners attached to certain array of elements.

As I am adding the event listeners I cannot get a reference to the parameters I needs. I have been doing some research and found out that can be solved using closures, but I can't figure out very well how to do it

here is my function reference

```
const editTask = function (element, taskIndex) {
   const handler = function(event) {
   // my code ...
   }
}
```

and this is how I am adding the listeners

```
function addEditListeners() {
  const editButtons = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("edit-btn"));
  console.log('editbuttons', editButtons);
  //editButtons.forEach(function (element) {
  //    element.removeEventListeners("click", editTask);
  //});
  editButtons.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("click", handler);
  });
}
```

I have tried sending the parameters in parenthesis but the editTask is undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Listener should have a function reference. Basically you can't specify parameters at the time of listener assignment. A handler function will always be called with the event being passed as the first argument. To pass other arguments, you can wrap your listener into an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you are passing `handler` which only exists in the editTask function and nowhere else, your listener adding function should be like this

```
editButtons.forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.addEventListener("click", (e) => editTask(element, index, e));
  });
```

Also I see you want an event in there as well so you should pass it in edit task

```
const editTask = function (element, taskIndex, event) {
   const handler = function(event) {
   // my code ...
   }
   handler(event);
}
```

Comment: thanks, thats works for the adding, forget about the event I don't need that. How can I validate that I can remove the listener because when is the first time it throws error trying to remove a listener that does not exist

Comment: you can wrap your code in ```try { } catch() {}``` when you call the ```element.removeEventListener("click", editTask)``` more info about removeEventListener you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)